# RegEx : How can I extract a certain part and modify it?

Tags: regex

I'd like to extract a certain part of a string and modify it by using a regular expression.

A given string is `TestcaseVzwPerformance_8_2_1_4_1_FDD2`.
I'd like to extract the part `8_2_1_4_1` from the string and then replace the underscores `_` with dots `.` So the expected result needs to be `8.2.1.4.1`.

The numbers and length of the given string can be different.
For example,

```
Given string                        // Expected result
TestcaseVzwCqi_3_9_Test2            // 3.9
TestcaseVzwSvd1xRttAclr_6_6_2_3     // 6.6.2.3
TestcaseVzwCsiFading_9_4_1_1_1_FDD4 // 9.4.1.1.1
```

Here is my RegEx:

```
((?:\D{0,}_)(\d(_\d)*)(.*))
```

The numbered capturing group - `$2` - contains `8_2_1_4_1` but with underscores.
Can I replace the underscores with dots?

It needs to be done in one RegEx and a Replace.

Comment: What RegEx flavour, and what language?

Comment: A general way is `(?<=\d)_(?=\d)` replace with `.`

Answer (score 0):

regex cannot modify, for example with `sed`

```
echo TestcaseVzwPerformance_8_2_1_4_1_FDD2 | 
sed -E 's/[^_]*_(([_0-9])+)_.*/\1/;s/_/./g'         

8.2.1.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Bash string, you can use a Bash regex to capture and Bash parameter expansions to replace:

```
$ s="TestcaseVzwSvd1xRttAclr_6_6_2_3"
$ [[ $s =~ ^[^_]*_([[:digit:]_]+)_* ]] && tmp=${BASH_REMATCH[1]//_/.} && echo "${tmp%.}"
6.6.2.3
```

Which can be in a loop:

```
while read -r line; do 
   if [[ $line =~ ^[^_]*_([[:digit:]_]+)_* ]]; then 
      tmp=${BASH_REMATCH[1]//_/.}
      echo "\"$line\" => ${tmp%.}"
   fi   
done <<< 'Given string                      
TestcaseVzwCqi_3_9_Test2            
TestcaseVzwSvd1xRttAclr_6_6_2_3     
TestcaseVzwCsiFading_9_4_1_1_1_FDD4'
```

Prints:

```
"TestcaseVzwCqi_3_9_Test2" => 3.9
"TestcaseVzwSvd1xRttAclr_6_6_2_3" => 6.6.2.3
"TestcaseVzwCsiFading_9_4_1_1_1_FDD4" => 9.4.1.1.1
```

You can use the same loop to process a file.

If you have a file, you may as well use `gawk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="_[[:digit:]_]+"} 
      /_[[:digit:]]/ {sub(/^_/,"", $1); sub(/_$/,"",$1); gsub(/_/,".",$1); print $1}' file
3.9
6.6.2.3
9.4.1.1.1
```